# Ignorando arquivos no git que não tenham extensão

Tags: git

Programando em C++ para Linux, quando compilo o código com o g++, é gerado três arquivos:

> arquivo.o
>
> arquivo

sendo que o último, neste sistema, é o binário executável gerado pelo cpp.

Se eu quisesse ignorar os arquivos:

```
#.gitignore

*.o

# ... outros arquivos desnecessarios, alem do cpp
```

Como eu posso fazer para ignorar os arquivos sem extensão?

Answer (score 3):

O truque é ignorar tudo e depois excluir os arquivos que você quer

```
# ignore tudo
*
# exclua os subdiretórios
!/**/
# exclua os arquivos com extensão
!*.*
```

Mas não recomendo fazer isso. O uso padrão é criar um subdiretório `build`, por exemplo, acrescentar esse diretório no `gitignore` e criar os executáveis lá. Provavelmente no futuro você vai querer criar arquivos sem extensão como `Makefile` `MANUAL` ou algo do gênero.